# Notation question (regarding weak topology / dual spaces)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, notation

Let $X $ be a Banach space and $X^* $ its dual space. Let $\{x_n\} $ be a sequence that converges weakly to $x\in X $, and $\{f_n\}\subset X^* $ a sequence that converges in the strong topology of $X^*$. Show that $$(x_n,f_n)\to (x,f).$$ I didn't manage to give a precise meaning to $(\cdot ,\cdot) $: can you tell me what does this notation stand for?  (I didn't find anything in Wikipedia) Thanks

Comment: It's function evaluation: $(x,f)=f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks; then $f_n (x_n)$ converges to the same limit of $f_n (x) $ because $x_n $ converges weakly to $x $. Plus, since $|f_n(x) - f (x)|$ converges to $0$ for every element of $X $, $f_n (x) $ converges to $f (x) $. Is it correct?

Comment: You need more than weak convergence of $(x_n)$ to prove your first claim. I would prove the original statement by first noting $$|f_n(x_n)-f(x)|\le |f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|+|f(x_n)-f(x)|\le\Vert f_n-f\Vert \Vert x_n\Vert +|f(x_n)-f(x)|.$$ (Keep in mind going forward that weakly convergent sequences are norm-bounded.)

Comment: Thank you, very clear

Comment: @Dorian You should write an answer to your own question and accept it.